# How to set chart legend's position (achartengine)

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

My legend is running into my x axis values, I can't figure out how to fix it.

I already tried both

```
renderer.setFitLegend(true);
```

and

```
renderer.setLegendHeight(10);
```

Both of them just make the legend disappear and the latter one sometimes cuts my chart from the screen.

Here is how it currently looks: [image]

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 50, 50, 25, 22 });`